# How Can I install a 4inch ceiling fan in a 3 inch hole?

Tags: lighting, ceiling, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

[image]

I’ve circled the ceiling mount holes in blue and the fan mount holes in yellow. 
As you can see, the fan mount holes are wider apart than the ceiling’s holes.

Also I’ve tried drilling into the ceiling. Drilling into the ceiling just leaves a hole and the screws fall right out.

The fan is a “fanimation” fan. My house was built in the 80s

Note: in this photo I had the “adjustable flaps” of my universal cross bar on backwards. I needed to turn them around so they were “slidable”

Comment: Are you sure this is a fan rated box to begin with?

Comment: To put a fine point on the @ThreePhaseEel question: it looks like you are trying to attach a fan to a box that can't support it. Take another picture of the box without everything in the way, and we'll have an opinion. IF the box is adequate, you simply need to drop bolts down from the outside ears.

Comment: And don't worry too much -- if the box isn't adequate, you'll be able to install a new junction box without any drywall patching. 20 bucks worth of parts and 30 minutes will be well worth the peace of mind knowing that your fan isn't coming crashing down on your head any time soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I measured the “universal cross bar” so the flaps were at the right distance for my fan mount. 
I then realized I could screw the universal cross bar into the smaller ceiling mount.

I then screwed the fan mount into the “flaps” of the crossbar (which is pretty flush with the ceiling) and into the ceiling.

Even though there is “nothing on the other side” of the flaps, when I screwed the fan mount into the “flaps” of the “universal cross bar” - it does not appear that the fan will rip out of the ceiling.

I think the reason the fan doesn’t rip out of the ceiling is because the screw that went into the flap is a pretty tight fit

[image]

Comment: Happy for you that you got something to work, but I'll say it again: we (who do this for a living) weren't sure that the junction box you're hanging a heavy/dynamic load on was designed for that load.

Comment: Yeah I am a bit concerned about that too. I think it said it was good for 35 Lbs. I hope it is ok

Comment: I promise I'll shut up after this. But it's not any of the hardware you added today. It's the box in the ceiling I'm raving about. Some are made for ceiling fans; some aren't. It's not a given that you've got a junction box that can successfully hold a fan. /rant